# PHP syntax error when declaring a constant

Tags: php, syntax-error

The error I'm getting here is:

**Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected 'CASE' (T_CASE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in **[filename]** on line **4**

```
<?php

class PartCategories {
    const CASE = 1;
    const PROCESSOR = 2;
    const HARD_DRIVE = 3;
    const MEMORY = 4;
}
```

Can't say I've tried anything but for the life of me can't see what's wrong here.

Why is this a syntax error?

Comment: CASE is a reserved word in PHP, used as part of a switch statement

Comment: yes CASE is a reserved word. Please change to some other name.

Comment: I'm aware of that but assumed it's not that because it's uppercase.

Comment: PHP doesn't care much about that.

Answer (score 3):

`case` or `CASE` is already reserved by PHP for the `switch` statement. You can't redefine this as a constant, just as you cant define a `const FUNCTION` or something similar.

You're going to have to change the name of the constant.

Comment: Would have +1'ed this had Mark not commented before you :p

Comment: @aspirin: you said it. :P

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that PHP is not case sensitive.
So "case", "Case", "caSE", "CAsE" and like are same thing.

And you already know that case is a php reserved keyword it can't be use for variable name.

You can initialize your class like
$obj = new PartCategories();
 or paRTCATEgories(); 
or PARTCATEGORIES();
mEANS tO sAY THAt PHp iS CaSE INSEnsitive.