# Laravel throwing parse error whenever model is referenced in Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a pretty major problem with my code. Whenever I reference my model in my controller, Laravel throws a parse error. I have gone through my code many times, and do not see any grammatical problems or anything. Anyway, here is my code:

```
<?php
class CaseController extends BaseController{

public function index()
{

$cases = Case::all();

return View::make('index', compact('cases'));
}

public function create(){

    return View::make('create');
}

public function handleCreate(){

    $case = new Case;
    $case->name=        Input::get('name');
    $case->value=       Input::get('value');
    $case->contentions= Input::get('contentions');
    $case->notes=       Input::get('notes');
    $case->side=        Input::get('side');

    $case->save();

}

}
```

Here is my Eloquent model:

```
<?php

class Case extends Eloquent{


}
```

The parse error is thrown on this line:

```
$cases = Case:all();
```

However, when I erase the line

```
$cases = Case:all();
```

The parse error is thrown on this line:

```
$case = new Case;
```

It seems that whenever i mention the model Case in my code, laravel throws a parse error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: CASE is a reserved word in PHP, used in switch statements.... it's the [second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932473/php-syntax-error-when-declaring-a-constant) today that this issue has cropped up

Comment: Wow, thanks guys, I feel dumb, but i appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE` ***is*** a reserved word used in [switch statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), example:

```
switch($a) {
    case 'foo':
        $b = true;
        break;
    case 'bar':
        $b = false;
        break;
    default:
        die('Not found!');
}
```

You are going to need to rename your class to something different.  Also when initializing a class, the proper syntax is:

```
$case = new Case();
// instead of:
// $case = new Case;
```

Comment: Note: you *can* initialize a class without parenthesis

Comment: I know, but would you consider it the *proper* syntax?